# EF Core lazy loader behaviour with new entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, lazy-loading

The EF Core docs on [lazy loading without proxies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/lazy#lazy-loading-without-proxies) reference this example:

```
public class Blog
{
    private ICollection<Post> _posts;

    public Blog()
    {
    }

    private Blog(ILazyLoader lazyLoader)
    {
        LazyLoader = lazyLoader;
    }

    private ILazyLoader LazyLoader { get; set; }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Post> Posts
    {
        get => LazyLoader.Load(this, ref _posts);
        set => _posts = value;
    }
}
```

So we have a parameterless constructor and the lazy loader injection constructor. The docs then say this:

> This method doesn't require entity types to be inherited from or
> navigation properties to be virtual, and allows entity instances
> created with new to lazy-load once attached to a context.

So what does this mean exactly for new instances? An entity created by EF core will have the lazy loader injected but a `new` entity will not. Does this imply that once a new item is added to the context the lazy loader backing field should get updated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So what does this mean exactly for new instances? An entity created by EF core will have the lazy loader injected but a new entity will not. Does this imply that once a new item is added to the context the lazy loader backing field should get updated?

This is exactly what it means. Note that *attached to a context* here

> allows entity instances created with new to lazy-load once attached to a context.

means *tracked* (the usual term they use in most of the places), in other words, any operation which adds the entity to the context change tracker - `Attach`, `Add`, `Update`, `Remove`, setting `EntityEntry.State` to  anything except `EntityState.Detached`, entity created by tracking query etc.

Unfortunately the documentation does not explain all the details, so following is some additional information retrieved by experiment:

First, as explained above, the lazy loader service property is set when the entity is tracked. But the opposite is also true - the property is nulled out when entity is untracked, for instance by setting `State` to `EntityState.Detached`.

Second is the actual requirements for the property itself. The docs say at the end:

> **Note**
>
> The constructor parameter for the lazy-loading delegate must be called "lazyLoader". Configuration to use a different name than this is planned for a future release.

which is not exactly correct.

The actual requirement is to have

- **property** with getter **and setter**
- with any visibility (usually `private`)
- with *case insensitive* name "LazyLoader"
- and *type* either `ILazyLoader` or `Action<object, string>`

**Update:** Additional requrements found by OP:

- In case the service property is defined in a base class, the getter should be visible to the derived class, i.e. at least `protected`. The setter could be `private`.
- The property must not be decorated with [`NotMapped`] attribute or `Ignored` fluently.

At the same time, the "injection" constructor with the corresponding argument is **not** required. When creating entity instances, EF Core will use any constructor and set the lazy loader service property the same way as when it tracks an existing entity instance.

Comment: I asked this question because I do not see this behaviour in our application code. The lazy loader property does not get updated for new entities when they are tracked. If I set up a simple demo project then I do see the documented behaviour. Obviously something is amiss with our application code even though the lazy loader property meets the requirements above.

Comment: Yeah, that's weird. I really tested all these scenarios and they worked as mentioned. The only other requirement is to make sure  `dbContext.ChangeTracker.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;` which is the default.

Comment: Found my issue (2 in fact). 1. My `LazyLoader` property is defined in a base class and is not found with `private` visibility, it has to be at least `protected` (though the setter can be `private`). 2. In earlier times the property was public and was decorated with an anomalous `[NotMapped]`. We should perhaps update your answer to note the potential visability issues.

Comment: @JonathanMitchell Great, glad you found it! Answer updated, thanks.

Comment: This explanation does not work for me. I am returning data retrieved via a table join using an IQueryable<myDataType>, where myDataType has a LazyLoader implemented as described in this answer, so I expect EF Core (6) to inject a lazy loader, which it doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

EF in a way breaks the rules of encapsulation to a degree when it comes to private constructors and setters. It's not a bad thing since the real goal of making these private is to ensure the access to your code is organized without the clutter of guessing which and what to use, but at the same time EF will ignore those limitations via reflection.

When you `Attach` an entity to a `DbContext`, that `DbContext` will check the attached entity for property types it can inject. This includes including the `ILazyLoader` which EF will use the private setter to wire up. So you can `new` up a new entity, and once attached to a DbContext it will have access to the lazy loader.

Comment: What happens when I create a new item and `Add` to the context rather than `Attach` it? Should I expect to end up with an entity in the unchanged tracked state with the lazy loader set?

Comment: Yes, adding a new entity would be considered associating the entity to the `DbContext` same as attaching so after adding the `ILazyLoader` would be accessible.