# EF Core 7+: How to get entity with lazy loading after Add/Save

Tags: entity-framework-core, .net-7.0

```cs
var bill1 = _context.Bills.Find(1);
var partyName = bill.Party.Name; // works

var bill2 = new Bill {
                      PartyId = 76
                    };
_context.Bills.Add(bill2);
_context.SaveChanges();

var partyName = bill2.Party.Name; // Party is null here

var bill3 = _context.Bills.Find(bill2.BillId);
// Party is still null here because Bill is being returned
// from tracker not DB, I assume
partyName = bill3.Party.Name;
```

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57185641/59791) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70549605/59791) I understand why `bill2.Party` is not lazy loaded and is null. There are two options to make `Party` lazy loaded immediately after Adding/Saving: `CreateProxy` or `ILazyLoader`.

But let's say it is overkill for me and I just want to reselect Bill from Db and have my Party lazy loaded for bill3 after saving new Bill to db.

I know I could detach bill2 and then bill3 should work but it is just ugly to mess with low level context stuff in your api controller.

Isn't there a simple straight forward way of doing this?

Comment: If you want to ensure lazy loading is available, you want to use `DbSet.CreateProxy` rather than `new`0ing a Bill entity. I don't recommend using `Find ` unless you're explicitly only interested in the single entity and no related data. `Single` or `First` are better options and support eager loading where you want related data, or for read-based operations use projection with `Select` rather than relying on lazy loading. Code like `bill1 = _context.Bills.Find(1); var partyName = bill.Party.Name;` works, but can get extremely expensive.

Answer (score 2):

> But let's say it is overkill for me and I just want to reselect Bill from Db and have my Party lazy loaded for bill3 after saving new Bill to db.

You can use change tracking APIs ([ReferenceEntry.Load](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.referenceentry.load?view=efcore-7.0) / [CollectionEntry.Load](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.collectionentry.load?view=efcore-7.0) or their `Async` equivalents) to ensure navigation property is loaded. These methods work for both lazy and explicit loading, and do nothing if the navigation property is already loaded.

e.g.

```cs
var bill = new Bill { PartyId = 76 };
_context.Bills.Add(bill);
_context.SaveChanges();

_context.Entry(bill).Reference(e => e.Party).Load(); // <--
Debug.Assert(bill.Party != null);
```

Comment: This will fetch Party from db immediately while I would prefer to get Party Proxy, and other properties' Proxies, so that I can create general solution and use it in repository Add method. Any idea?

Comment: I've suggested this because you said you don't want using `CreateProxy` because it is "overkill for you"  (not sure why). If you need proxy, just instead of `new Bill()` use `_context.CreateProxy<Bill>()`

Answer (score 0):

First, your `bill1.Party` will also be `null` **unless** it was populated from the database earlier.

There are two simple ways to get Party data.

First (I would argue, not so good):

`var bill1 = _context.Bills.Include(b => b.Party).First(b => b.Id == 1);`

Second approach (explicitly define the fields that you want):

```
var bill1 = _context.Bills.Where(b => b.Id == 1)
    .Select(b => new() {
        b.Id,
        b.PartyId,
        PartyName = b.Party.Name
    }).First();
```